# How to display the selected option after being saved

Tags: html, dropdown

I have a dropdown list in my Edit page, where the user will update the status by selecting a value, click save and the new value is updated in the Database. But the thing is, when i view it, the dropdown list doesn't change.

Example: In the database it says "Approved", but the value displayed in the dropdown is "Pending" (see image below)

[image]

Can someone help me display the user selected option, Thanks!

**Front End**

```
<select class="form-control" id="LV_STATUS" name="LV_STATUS">
    <option>Pending</option>
    <option>Approved</option>
    <option>Denied</option>
</select>
```

**Back End**

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    eMP_LEAVES.LV_STATUS = Request.Form["LV_STATUS"].ToString();
    db.Entry(eMP_LEAVES).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have to set a loop that will look for your database status like i have done below this is a function which accepts the database value and it will loop in the select tag.

I hope this make sense and you got the point

Thank you :)

```js
var LV_STATUS = document.getElementById('LV_STATUS')

function indexx(database_Value){
    for(let i=0 ; i<LV_STATUS.options.length ; i++)
    {
        if(database_Value === LV_STATUS.options[i].text)
        {
            LV_STATUS.options[i].selected = true
            return
        }
    }
    }
    
    indexx("Pending") // pass database value here
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="LV_STATUS" name="LV_STATUS">
    <option>Pending</option>
    <option>Approved</option>
    <option>Denied</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selected` attribute to display user selected option as follows

```
<select class="form-control" id="LV_STATUS" name="LV_STATUS">
    <option (LV_STATUS=='Pending' ? 'selected="selected"' : '')>Pending</option>
    <option (LV_STATUS=='Approved' ? 'selected="selected"')>Approved</option>
    <option (LV_STATUS=='Denied' ? 'selected="selected"')>Denied</option>
</select>
```

**Remember:** Replace LV_STATUS with the variable which contains the status value stored in DB